# How to keep duplicate items with set subtraction?

Tags: list, groovy, difference

By groovy way, the code like:

```
def l1 = [] as List;
def l2 = [] as List;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    l1 << i;
    l2 << i;
    l1 << i;
}

println(l1);
println(l2);

def l = l1-l2;
println(l);
```

The l is empty, but I want it be [0,1,2,3,4], just subtract the item once(if there is only on item in l2).

Answer (score 2):

It works that way, because `List.minus(Object el)` searches for all elements matching `el` object and removes them from the input list. Alternatively you can make usage of `List.removeElement(Object el)` which searches for the first element and removes it from the list. This method can be combined with Groovy's `inject` method:

```
def l1 = [] as List
def l2 = [] as List

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    l1 << i
    l2 << i
    l1 << i
}

def l3 = l2.inject(l1) { List list, el ->
    list.removeElement(el)
    return list
}

println "l1 is ${l1}"
println "l2 is ${l2}"
println "l3 is ${l3}"
```

Output:

```
l1 is [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
l2 is [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
l3 is [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

In this example we use `l2` list to iterate over its elements and we pass `l1` as our initial value to `inject` method. Then for each element from `l2` list we remove the list we passed to the inject method and we return it so in the next iteration step this list is seen as `list` variable in the closure passed to `inject`. `List.removeElement(Object el)` is a safe method and there is no exception thrown if we try to remove an element that does not exist in the list.

However the code I have shown you has one significant drawback - it passes `l1` to inject method and this list gets modified by it. That's why when you print `l1` in the end you will see it is equal `l3` we just created with inject method. The solution to this problem is fairly simple - instead of passing a refernce to `l1` you can create a copy of this list, e.g. with `new ArrayList<>(l1)` and now `l1` list does not gets updated by the inject method.

```
def l3 = l2.inject(new ArrayList<>(l1)) { List list, el ->
    list.removeElement(el)
    return list
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, now I use l2.each { l1.removeElement(it); } to do that. I think there maybe a groovy way to do that, like l1.removeOnce(l2).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that removal is done on the basis of element equality.

As an alternative, you can use indices to search the larger list, and build a `diff` list that includes all elements from `l1` except the ones at first index of matches:

```
//find the first index of each l2 element in l1:
def match = l2.collect{l1.indexOf(it)}

//find indices of all elements that were not found in l1
def indices = (0..(-1+l1.size())).grep{!match.contains(it)}

//make a list of all elements that were not selected
//and that's basically the result of YOUR l1-l2
def diff = indices.collect{l1[it]}

println(diff)
```

That outputs:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Please note that this is not a generic method. It's completely based on your example above and assumes, for example, that `l1` is a superset of `l2`, but it gives an idea.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For small lists the suggested solutions are fine. You could improve time complexity from *O(mn)* to *O(m+n)* without nested looping using the imperative solution  [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75667177/15053047).

Restricting myself to functional style I could not come up with a better solution than

```
    List l1 = (0..<5).collectMany{ [it, it] }
    List l2 = (0..<5).toList()

    Map l2CountBy = l2.countBy { it }

    List l3 = l1.withIndex()
            .groupBy { it[0] }
            .collectEntries { val, indices -> [val, indices.collect { it[1] }.dropRight(l2CountBy[val] ?: 0)] }
            .collectMany { val, indices -> indices.collect{ index -> [index, val] } }
            .sort { it[0] }
            .collect { it[1] }
```

Not easy to read and probably a good example for overusing functional style, but it's fun to let these great Groovy features play together.