# difference between two lists that include duplicates

Tags: arraylist, groovy

I have a problem with two lists which contain duplicates

```
a = [1,1,2,3,4,4]
b = [1,2,3,4]
```

I would like to be able to extract the differences between the two lists ie.

```
c = [1,4]
but if I do c = a-b I get c =[]
```

It should be trivial but I can't find out  :(
I tried also to parse the biggest list and remove items from it when I find them in the smallest list but I can't update lists on the fly, it does not work either

has anyone got an idea ?
thanks

Answer (score 3):

You see an empty `c` as a result, because removing e.g. `1` removes all elements that are equal `1`.

```
groovy:000> [1,1,1,1,1,2] - 1
===> [2]
```

What you need instead is to remove each occurrence of specific value separately. For that, you can use Groovy's `Collection.removeElement(n)` that removes a single element that matches the value.  You can do it in a regular for-loop manner, or you can use another Groovy's collection method, e.g. `inject` to reduce a copy of `a` by removing each occurrence separately.

```
def c = b.inject([*a]) { acc, val -> acc.removeElement(val); acc }

assert c == [1,4]
```

Keep in mind, that `inject` method receives a copy of the `a` list (expression `[*a]` creates a new list from the `a` list elements.) Otherwise, `acc.removeElement()` would modify an existing `a` list. The `inject` method is an equivalent of a popular *reduce* or *fold* operation. Each iteration from this example could be visualized as:

```
--inject starts--
acc = [1,1,2,3,4,4]; val = 1; acc.removeElement(1) -> return [1,2,3,4,4] 
acc = [1,2,3,4,4]; val = 2; acc.removeElement(2) -> return [1,3,4,4]
acc = [1,3,4,4]; val = 3; acc.removeElement(3) -> return [1,4,4]
acc = [1,4,4]; val = 4; acc.removeElement(4) -> return [1,4]
-- inject ends -->
```

PS: Kudos to almighty [tim_yates](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6509/tim-yates) who recommended improvements to that answer. Thanks, Tim!

Comment: damn ! I've just realized that it's perfect in this precise case but it does not provide all the differences ... eg. if b = [1,2,3,4,5] it won't show 5 in the result, but only the duplicates. Sorry, I was not clear enough in my first post (I edited it to change duplicates => differences) as my lists may contain duplicates but not only :/

Answer (score 0):

the most readable that comes to my mind is:

```
a = [1,1,2,3,4,4]
b = [1,2,3,4]
c = a.clone()
b.each {c.removeElement(it)}
```

if you use this frequently you could add a method to the List metaClass:

```
List.metaClass.removeElements = { values -> values.each { delegate.removeElement(it) } }
a = [1,1,2,3,4,4]
b = [1,2,3,4]
c = a.clone()
c.removeElements(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers posted are short and elegant and should work in most cases. Note that `removeElement` iterates through a list each time it is called, resulting in a time complexity of *O(nm)*, where *n, m* are the size of the lists. For large lists, this can be improved to *O(n+m)*. Here an example using the good old imperative style (mutating variables...I know)

```
List a = [1,1,2,3,4,4]
List b = [1,2,3,4]

Map bCountBy = b.countBy { it }

List c = []
for(elem in a){
    if (bCountBy[elem]) {
        bCountBy[elem] -= 1
    } else {
        c << elem
    }
}

assert c == [1,4]
```